# Fixed content with viewport height

Tags: javascript, parallax, stellar.js

I'm creating a parallax site using stellar.js and am using viewport height to determine the height of elements. Each section is vertically stacked on the section before it, each with `height: 50vh` On the third container down I am trying to give the inner content a fixed position, so it does not move while the rest of the site moves around (and over) it. However I am struggling to figure out how to achieve this.

I've tried giving it `top: 125vh` and used `top: 50%` which is as close as I've got but the effect is undesirable and I've had issues with overlapping, which may be a separate issue (but one I may run into with any fix, so help is appreciated). The desired effect can be seen on this site http://www.mohi.me/ in the about section. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `position: fixed` this will give that container a fixed position in the viewport. Can you recreate your example to show us?

Comment: I'm building live and can link you right to it
http://astryk.com/ayce/test.php

Comment: that was for @Adjit btw

Comment: Looks fine... not seeing what the issue is